# R: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04, dplyr

I am trying to install R packages in ubuntu 14.04. All other packages installed successfully, but 'dplyr' package failed to install.

I used the command below:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('dplyr', repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

....

```
 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dplyr’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpiKWYoQ/downloaded_packages’
  Warning message:
 In install.packages("dplyr", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") :
 installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status
```

R version 3.2.4 Revised

Comment: maybe try via apt-get... `sudo apt-get install r-cran-dplyr`

Comment: You should look through the `...` portion of the installation process to see if any needed libraries are missing.

Comment: Unless you have some very special issues, you should really install packages from the R console: `install.packages("dplyr")`.